# Auto Scrolling Horizontal ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, horizontalscrollview, android-adapterview

I use this [lib](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34) for implementing `Horizontal ListView`.
The component based on `AdapterView`.

How can I implement ability to autoscroll the component horizontally infinitely?

I tried do it with `Scroller` widget, but it has no method for infinite scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check this library in order to make horizontal listview and scroll is automatically
https://github.com/blessenm/AndroidAutoScrollListView